# Dynamics CRM 2016: access product details in quote template

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

I would like to pull some additional data from the product entity to a quote. 
To create a quote, I use a Word template. 
When creating the Word template for the quote entity, I can only select the related entity "Quote Product". I am missing the related products (from the "Product" entity).

The entity "Quote Product" is related to the entity "Product".
How do I access the information of the "Product" entity in the Word template?
When creating it, I can only choose to add the "Quote Product" entity.

[image]

I somehow need to find a way to add the "Quote Product" entity as well as the related "Product" entity.

Is this possible? Preferably without coding.

Answer (score 0):

As far as what you're allowed to include in the template, you have to copy the information from the Product to the Quote Product.

Comment: The feature anyway is very new, quite limited and buggy as hell so I expect it to become better with future updates...

Comment: It would be OK for me to copy the record from product to quote product entity. Do you have any ideas on how this could be achieved?

Comment: Off the top of my head, a plugin on pre-create of the quote product grabbing the data from the referenced product should work fine for this